# Cannot feed value of shape (480, 720, 3) for Tensor u'input_ph:0', which has shape '(?, 2048)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have trained a network based on Inception to learn on new classes. The input tensor is of shape [None, 2048]... my test input image is taken using the photo booth mac app which has pixel dimensions 480 x 720.

How do i feed the new image in to get a prediction on a new image?

Here is my test setup:

```
import argparse
import tensorflow as tf
import utils
from PIL import Image

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--pb_file", required=True, type=str, help="Frozen model file to import")
    parser.add_argument("--img_path", required=True, type=str, help="Path to image for input to model")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    graph = utils.load_graph(args.pb_file)

    for op in graph.get_operations():
        print(op.name + '\t' + str(op.values()))

    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_ph:0')
    y = graph.get_tensor_by_name('FC_layers_1/FC_4/Softmax:0')

    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        feed_dict = {x: Image.open(args.img_path)}
        y_out = sess.run(y, feed_dict=feed_dict)
        print(y_out)
```

`--pb_file` argment is for the final frozen model
`--img_path` is the image i am trying to feed into the trained model
`input_ph:0` is the input placeholder
`FC_layers_1/FC_4/Softmax:0` softmax output i expect

Comment: Is your question about resizing your test input (480x720x3) to 2048 size vector? I guess the way to handle this would be to resize your image to something like 24x36x3 reshape it to a single dimensional vector of size 2592 and crop the end to get a 2048 vector. You can use the [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to do it pythonic way or use [tf.Image](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image) API to do that tensorflow-y way.

Comment: Why is your expected model input size? (?, 2048) doesn't make too much sense. Tensorflow models usually expect data in NHCW format - (Batch, Height, Width, Channels). it doesn't make a lot of sense to have only 2 input dimensions. if we're speaking of a flattened array - make sure you know the input resolution. Note that it's not an RGB image, since 2048 is not divisible by 3.